# c# replacing text without pushing out other text in row

Tags: c#, text, replace, insert

I am very new to C# so forgive my ignorance. I tried to search for something about this but couldn't find anything.
I am replacing the word user with the windows login name in a .txt file where I also have character limits to allow my file to be imported into an ERP system. When I replace the word user with a name that is longer than 4 characters, it pushes everything in that row out and my ERP system rejects it. How do I keep it from pushing out the other text in the row? This is my code:

```
            string userName = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileToWrite);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToCopy))
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(fileToCopy, newLocation, true);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No such file");
                return;
            }

            System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
            objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToWrite);
            do
            {
                userName = userName.Replace("user", System.Environment.UserName);
                textLine = textLine + objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
            } while (objReader.Peek() != -1);
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(newLocation, true);
                objWriter.Write(userName);
                objWriter.Close();
            }
            objReader.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you doing that with `userName` inside the loop? Also, all you're ever writing to `newLocation` is the `userName`, and you're not using `textLine` at all.

Comment: What is the format of the file? (I don't mean .txt, I mean what format is the data it contains in).

Comment: ugh. Is the a 'flat file'? If so, then you can't change the length of each line.

Comment: These are good thoughts, but shouldn't he first be actually writing the proper content to the file before checking why its badly formatted?

Comment: I am getting the information that I want from the script, but I just need to have the script "press the Insert key" and replace the word user while eating up spaces that are already present between it and the next value. It is formatted like a spreadsheet with each value being spaced out by a varying character limit.

Comment: If that happens, this code in the question isn't the code at hand.

Comment: The truth is stranger than fiction